# Swift - Assigning Overloaded Function to Variable

Tags: swift

I am getting a compile time error that myFunc reference is ambiguous.

```
func f (s: String) -> String { return "version 1: " + s }
func f(sourceString s: String) -> String { return "version 2: " + s }
var myFunc: (String)-> String = f as (sourceString : String)->String
```

How can I explicitly reference each version of the overloaded function, f, in the example above? If I comment out either declaration of `func f` it will compile and work. But I would like to know how to reference each of the functions if both are declared.  Thanks.

Comment: Let me know If my answer helped you. I can try to help more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting one this.  I don’t think it’s possible without doing something along the lines of @marcos’s suggestion.  The problem you is you can “cast away” the names in tuples:

```
let named_pair = (s: "hello", i: 1)
named_pair.s  // hello

let anon_pair = named_pair as (String,Int)
// or anon_pair: (String,Int) = named_pair, if you prefer
anon_pair.s  // no such member 's'
```

Now suppose you define two functions, identical except one has named arguments:

```
func f(s: String, i: Int) { println("_: \(s)") }
func f(#s: String, #i: Int) { println("s: \(s)") }
```

You can then call it via tuples with named vs unnamed arguments:

```
f(named_pair)  // prints s: hello
f(anon_pair)   // prints _: hello

// but if you try to call a named argument function with unnamed tuples:
func g(# s: String, # i: Int) { println("s: \(s)") }
g(anon_pair)  // compiler error

let h = g
h(anon_pair)   // compiler error
h(named_pair)  // works
```

But because you can cast away these names you can do this:

```
// compiles and runs just fine...
(g as (String,Int)->())(anon_pair)
let k: (String,Int)->() = g
// as does this
k(anon_pair)
```

And this ability to do this means it’s not possible to use a type to disambiguate an function overloaded only by argument names, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. Great discussion on this by all.  Airspeed Velocity - I was afraid of that. Not as much from a practical perspective (I can always rename the function to avoid overloading), but more from an academic perspective. Seems kind of poor that a language supporting functions as first-class data types has scenarios where one cannot unambiguously reference overloaded functions. Ok - the academic in me is disappointed, but the pragmatist will concede this probably will hardly ever come up in "real life" :-)

Comment: Another approach I had thought of was to declare the second as a closure assigned to the variable initially. That would work also, but again, I was really hoping the language had a way to reference a function signature that included named parameter disambiguation.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how to do exactly what you want, but maybe this helps:

```
var myFunc1: (String)-> String = { s in f(sourceString: s) }
var myFunc2: (String)-> String = { s in f(s) }
```

You can now call:

```
let s1 = myFunc1("one")  // returns "version 2: one"
let s2 = myFunc2("two")  // returns "version 1: two"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Marcos. I agree by not overloading, I avoid the issue. I am more interested in how I can specify a specific function signature when the only difference is in the named parameters. My interest is as much academic (since the work around you mention would work). Is there any way to disambiguate the function reference other than separate names?

Answer (score 2):

Referencing `func f (s: String) -> String { return "version 1: " + s }`:

```swift
let myFunction = f(s:)
```

Referencing `func f(sourceString s: String) -> String { return "version 2: " + s }`:

```swift
let myFunction = f(sourceString:)
```

Referencing `func anotherFunction(_ param: Any) {}`:

```swift
let myFunction = anotherFunction(_:)
```

If you haven't overloaded the function, you don't need to explicity write out the parameter names when referencing the function.

Answer (score 1):

- Number of arguments should vary.
- If the number of arguments are same then their data types should
  vary.

**Example**

```
func f(x : String) -> NSString {
        return a
    }
func f(x : UInt) -> NSString {
            return "{\(x)}"
        }
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Functions in Swift are allowed to differ only by external parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. You can call one or the other:

```
println(f("test")) // version 1: test
println(f(sourceString: "test")) // version 2: test
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivica. I have no problem calling each function. But I would like a variable reference to each instead (functions as first-class types, should be able to point a variable to each function unambiguously).