# Reference method from different class as curried function

Tags: swift, methods, currying

There are two `merge` methods in `RACSignal`:

```
- (RACSignal *)merge:(RACSignal *)signal;
+ (RACSignal *)merge:(id<NSFastEnumeration>)signals;
```

When I write `RACSignal.merge` it references static method:

```
class func merge(signals: NSFastEnumeration!) -> RACSignal!
```

How to reference object method? I can't write `self.merge`, because it is in wrapper class and `self` is not `RACSignal`.

Comment: You can only call the instance method on an instance of `RACSignal` (or an instance of a subclass)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As methods in Swift are curried class functions, compiler has to decide which overload to choose.

To reference instance's `merge` method you need to specify it's exact type:

`let instanceMerge: RACSignal -> RACSignal! -> RACSignal! = RACSignal.merge`

Answer (score 3):

The curried class function and the curried instance function have
different signatures. Similarly as in

- [Swift - get reference to a function with same name but different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345950/swift-get-reference-to-a-function-with-same-name-but-different-parameters)

you can refer to each by specifying the signature explicitly.

I have no experience with RACSignal, so here is an artificial
example that hopefully can be applied in your case:

```
class MyClass {
    class func foo(s : String) {
        println("class foo: \(s)")
    }
    func foo(s : String) {
        println("instance foo: \(s)")
    }
}

// Reference to the class method:
let f1 : String -> Void = MyClass.foo

// Call the class method:
f1("bar")
// Output: class foo: bar

// Reference to the instance method:
let f2 : MyClass -> String -> Void = MyClass.foo

// Call the instance method:
let obj = MyClass()
f2(obj)("bar")
// Output: instance foo: bar
```