# How to call IMP in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Since **Swift2** you can use good ole':

```
class_getMethodImplementation(cls: AnyClass!, _ name: Selector) -> IMP
```

It returns `imp`. In `Objective-C` you just call it like:

```
implementation(self, selector)
```

But how to call it in **Swift**?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Perhaps you can instead use the fact that [Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/)? See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345950/swift-get-reference-to-a-function-with-same-name-but-different-parameters.

Comment: @MartinR Very useful article! Thanks.
I'm implementing subclass of some UIView. And I want to skip it's `super`'s 
`updateConstaints`, cause it affects my own layout. So my idea: get `super.super` implementation and call it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was trying to get runtime calls working on an instance method with parameter(s).  @Fabio's answer got me most of the way there.  Here's a full example for future googlers:

```
import Foundation

class X {
  @objc func sayHiTo(name: String) {
    print("Hello \(name)!")
  }
}

let obj = X()
let sel = #selector(obj.sayHiTo)
let meth = class_getInstanceMethod(object_getClass(obj), sel)
let imp = method_getImplementation(meth)

typealias ClosureType = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector, String) -> Void
let sayHiTo : ClosureType = unsafeBitCast(imp, ClosureType.self)
sayHiTo(obj, sel, "Fabio")
// prints "Hello Fabio!"
```

Comment: sayHiTo(obj, sel, "Lou")

Comment: For calling a private method: `let sel = Selector(("sayHiTo:"))` `let imp = obj.method(for:sel)`

Answer (score 15):

Based on the article [Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/) it's pretty easy to achieve the desired result:

```
typealias MyCFunction = @convention(c) (AnyObject, Selector) -> Void
let curriedImplementation = unsafeBitCast(implementation, MyCFunction.self)
curriedImplementation(self, selector)
```

Comment: Will check it later. Thanks!

Comment: @orkenstein you may have to change the types of the `typealias` since I don't know what you need.