# Passing function with multiple arguments as a closure in Swift

Tags: swift, function, closures

Is it possible to treat a function/method with multiple arguments as a closure in Swift? I'm particularly asking about the case where the initial function name is the same as other functions, and is differentiated by the number/type/name of its arguments. For example, take the following:

```
class Foo {
    func bar(bar: String) { print("bar: \(bar)") }
    func bar(bar: String, baz: String) {
        print("bar: \(bar), baz: \(baz)")
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
let bar1: (String) -> () = foo.bar
let bar2: (String, String) -> () = ???
```

The single argument `bar(_:)` function can be assigned to a variable of type `(String) -> ()` as done when assigning to `bar1`. However, I can't figure out how  `bar(_:baz:)` can be assigned to `bar2`. Is this possible in Swift? If so, how?

Comment: Similar question: [Swift - get reference to a function with same name but different parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28345950/swift-get-reference-to-a-function-with-same-name-but-different-parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write

```
let bar2: (String, String) -> () = foo.bar
```

The compiler actually infers the correct method from the type you specified for `bar2`.

Then calling `bar2("hi", "hi2")` will output

> bar: hi, baz: hi2

Note that omitting the specific type of `bar2` will cause the compiler to complain:
`error: ambiguous use of 'bar'`

Comment: Not quite sure why I couldn't make that leap, but indeed that does the trick. Thanks!