# How to disambiguate functions with differences only in parameter names in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following functions:

```
func moveThing(thing: AnyObject, toLeft length: Int) {}
func moveThing(thing: AnyObject, toRight length: Int) {}
```

However, when I pass one of the functions as a parameter, compiler complains about "Ambiguous use of 'moveThing'"

```
func exec(function: (AnyObject, Int) -> ()) {}
exec(moveThing) // Apparently ambiguous
exec(moveThing as (AnyObject, toLeft: Int) -> ()) // Still ambiguous
```

How can I solve the ambiguity?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - Assigning Overloaded Function to Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284924/swift-assigning-overloaded-function-to-variable)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not use moveThingLeft and moveThingRight? How do you plan to use it if you had been able to solve the ambiguity?

Comment: It's actually a port of existing Objective-C API. I can easily disambiguate them by using selectors "moveThing:toLeft:" and "moveThing:toRight:". However, were it designed with Swift in mind, the naming might be different. Also, Apple does it at lot, for example, in UITableViewDataSource, several of the methods begin with tableView(UITableView, XXX: NSIndexPath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An interesting question! I don't think you can at the moment, as it seems that parameter names are not part of the function reference name, though I couldn't find anything from Apple's reference documentation that explicitly dictates this.

Of course, for this particular example, you can use

```
exec({ moveThing($0, toLeft: $1) } )
exec({ moveThing($0, toRight: $1) } )
```

but I see what you are after with the simplified example.

Answer (score 3):

Swift Evolution proposal [SE-0021](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0021-generalized-naming.md) addressed this by allowing `moveThing(_:toLeft:)` to disambiguate these functions, and it is implemented in Swift 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I ran into this related situation recently. Might help somebody.



**TLDR**

Ultimately I solved the problem by just wrapping the method call in a closure like this:

```
let cancel: (Text) -> Alert.Button = { .cancel($0) }
```

**Long Winded Explanation**

When I type `Alert.Button.cancel` (from the SwiftUI framework), auto-complete shows me these options:

```
cancel(action: (() -> Void)?) // 1
cancel(label: Text) // 2
cancel() // 3
cancel(label: Text, action: (() -> Void)?) // 4
```

Naturally I thought this bit of code should work:

```
let cancel: (Text) -> Alert.Button = Alert.Button.cancel(_:)
```

However, the compiler says `Cannot convert value of type '((() -> Void)?) -> Alert.Button' to specified type '(Text) -> Alert.Button'`. Apparently it translates that signature to mean method 1 instead of method 2.

As it turns out, method 2 does not actually exist. Looking at the actual declarations in `Alert.swift` we find:

```
public static func cancel(_ label: Text, action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Alert.Button
public static func cancel(_ action: (() -> Void)? = {}) -> Alert.Button
```

So, `cancel(label:)` is *rendered* by auto-complete from `cancel(_:action:)` because the parameter `action` has a default value.

Conclusion: I made the mistake of assuming auto-complete was showing me individual method declarations. If the compiler tells you a method signature doesn't match what you expect, check the method *declaration*.